# Craft CMS FeedMe plugin - Process Instagram JSON Feed

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm trying out the new FeedMe plugin v2 beta 1 and am trying to download my recent photos posted on Instagram via the Instagram API. It appears Instagram is appending a cache parameters to the end of image URLs so when I try to download the images to a CraftCMS Assets folder Craft doesn't allow me to as it's not an allowed file extension.

The specific example is:

Instagram Request to get recent posts:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

example URL for image returned:
somepic_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=hghhh....

Does anyone have any bright ideas how to handle this so I can download the images at the URLs or some option / feature then could be incorporated into the plugin to remove querystrings from the end of asset urls?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the `cleanAssetUrls` configuration added just for you!

http://sgroup.com.au/plugins/feedme/getting-started/configuration